# How to make this razor view working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

in my MVC web apps,  this is the models which uses icollection object,

```
public class EmpProfile
{
    public int EmpProfileID { get; set; }
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    public string EmpNum { get; set; }
    public string ManagerEditor { get; set; }
    public string DocCreatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PerfPlan> PerfPlans { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProgReview> ProgReviews { get; set; }
 }
```

and this is PerfPlan model, the other model ProgReviews is similar like this one.

```
public class PerfPlan
     {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int EmpProfileID { get; set; }
        public string EmpName { get; set; }
        public string EmpNum { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        ....
         public virtual EmpProfile EmpProfile { get; set; }
    }
```

Basically, it builds one to many relationship between EmpProfile and PerfPlan, ProgReview. So one EmpProfile has 0 or many Performance plan and Progress Review data (model).Now, in my Index razor of EmpProfile, I want to list all PerfPlan and ProgReview which related to each EmpProfile, I build something like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<PerfM.Models.EmpProfile>

<table>

@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
<tr class="@selectedRow">
<td >
        @Html.ActionLink(@item.EmpName, "Index", new { id = item.EmpProfileID  })

    </td>
</tr>
 //here I need to list all PerfPlan and ProgReview related to this EmpProfile and list under this row.
```

Can any expert help me to continue the codes below? 
Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

Just use simple foreach loops like this (inside of your foreach loop) :

```
foreach(var plan in item.PerfPlans)
{
     // here you can access your PerfPlan properties like:
   <tr>
   <td> @plan.Id </td>
   <td> @plan.EmpName</td>
   <td> @plan.EmpNum </td>
   ...
   </tr>
}

foreach(var review in item.ProgReviews)
{
     ...
}
```

And in your Controller don't forget to include your collections:

```
var profiles  = context.EmpProfiles.Include("PerfPlans").Include("ProgReviews");
```

Comment: nice to know we can use Include, but in my case, it works if I do not use it, in my controller: public ActionResult Index(int? id)
        {
            Session["TempID"] = id;       
            return View(db.EmpProfiles.ToList());
        } and in my view, I still can get object PerfPlan by using item.Perfplan, now how to make this work? if (item.EmpProfileID.Equals(item.PerfPlans.Where(a => a.EmpProfileID)))

Comment: and how to make this work:  var test1 = item.PerfPlans.Where(a => a.EmpProfileID.Equals(Session["TempID"])).FirstOrDefault().PerfYear;